# Is there anyway to shorten this Java code?

Tags: java

Is there any way to validate height and weight in one do while?
Is there any way to test
`input.hasNextDouble() and height > 5 && height <= 500`
together on an `if` condition?

```java
    do {
            System.out.print("Height(cm): ");
            input.nextLine();
    
            if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
                height = input.nextDouble();
                if (height > 5 && height <= 500) {
                    isValid = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input\nPlease try again\n");
                    isValid = false;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input\nPlease try again\n");
                isValid = false;
            }
        } while (!(isValid));
    
        do {
            System.out.print("Weight(kg): ");
            input.nextLine();
    
            if (input.hasNextDouble()) {
                weight = input.nextDouble();
                if (weight > 0 && weight <= 500) {
                    isValid = true;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Invalid input\nPlease try again\n");
                    isValid = false;
                }
            } else {
                System.out.println("Invalid input\nPlease try again\n");
                isValid = false;
            }
        } while (!(isValid));
```

Comment: Well, the obvious idea would be to refactor the common code into a single method which could be shared.

Comment: One good thing that comes out of code like that is that you *could* give useful error messages. For instance "Invalid height: must be between 5 and 500."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining a common code into a single function and Using ternary operator to inline if condition.

```
    public static double takeInput(String heightOrWeight, int lowConstraint, int highConstraint) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        double validDouble = 0;
        boolean isValid = false;
        
        while(!(isValid)){
            System.out.print(heightOrWeight + ": ");
            input.nextLine();

            validDouble = input.hasNextDouble() ? input.nextDouble(): Integer.MIN_VALUE;
            
            if (validDouble > lowConstraint && validDouble <= highConstraint) {
                isValid = true;
            }
         
            if (!isValid) {
                 System.out.println("Invalid input\nPlease try again\n");
            }
        }
        return validDouble;
    }
```

Calling above method with appropriate parameters.

```
        double height = takeInput("Height(cm)", 5,500);
        double weight = takeInput("Weight(kg)", 0,500);
```

Comment: what does validDouble = input.hasNextDouble() ? input.nextDouble(): -1; means?

Comment: Its a ternary Operator. `variable x = (expression) ? value if true: value if false`
Instead of -1, you can put any Integer.MIN_VALUE or some other number which is not expected within the range